# i want to get the rank of a particular column value mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 columns: `value_id`, `customer_id`, `name`, and `score`

Now I have the `customer_id` and I want to get the rank by sorting the score values in DESC order

This is the MySQL command I have in my page

http://livetut.com/game/riddlehunt/score/list.php?start=0

```
$query2=" SELECT * FROM ridd ORDER BY score DESC ";
$count=$dbo->prepare($query2);
$count->execute();
$nume=$count->rowCount();
```

I want to get your rank from the `customer_id` which is unique for every user

I do not want to use the select statement again can i add some thing to the $query2 to get the value

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find your answer here : [how to get position rank of specific row using just mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584241/how-to-get-position-rank-of-specific-row-using-just-mysql-query?rq=1)

It seem's to be the same problem,

Here is the answer of the link above, if that can help you :

```
SELECT users1.id, (users1.points+users1.extra_points) AS total, COUNT(*)+1 AS rank
FROM users users1
INNER JOIN users users2 ON users1.points+users1.extra_points < users2.points+users2.extra_points
WHERE users1.id = $id
```

Good luck.

Comment: i do not want to use the select statement again can i add some thing to the $query to get the value

Comment: You can do query in the same query you had at the beginning. Like: SELECT ///*.ridd, users1.id, (users1.points+users1.extra_points) AS total, COUNT(*)+1 AS rank FROM ridd [INNERJOIN HERE] ORDER BY score DESC