# Updating a sql table with new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql and I have a table with columns: postid, userid, datestamp

I want to create a new column called 'entry' that numbers the entries chronologically according to datestamp

So, for the rows:

```
3705    1   2003-12-08 13:42:13
3711    15  2003-11-12 15:22:01
3701    2   2004-01-11 01:22:12
```

I want to end up with:

```
3705    1   2003-12-08 13:42:13 2
3711    15  2003-11-12 15:22:01 1
3701    2   2004-01-11 01:22:12 3
```

How can I perform this task?

Comment: You're looking for row ranking.

See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964811/row-rank-in-a-mysql-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN nr integer;

SET @rn := 0;

UPDATE tbl
SET    rn = (@rn := @rn + 1)
ORDER  BY datestamp, postid, userid;
```

Here is a [working demo](https://sqlize.com/6wE9maf8Uh).

I took the substitute for the missing window function `row_number()` in MySQL from [@OMG Ponies' Posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964811/row-rank-in-a-mysql-view).
Sort by `postid` and `userid` in addition to `datestamp` as the timestamp column is not guaranteed to be unique.
Read about [setting variables in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN entry INTEGER
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

For setting it to the ordered number you would use RANK function but MySQL doesn't have one, so will have to look for substitutes like this one:
http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to order chronologically  the dates you dont have to create another column. You can do it with a simple cursor.

```
private static String[] FROM = {_ID, COL_1, COL_NAME, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4}; //add your columns
private static String ORDER_BY = COL_NAME + " DESC"; //or ASC for ascending
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, FROM, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
```

and then just show the results from the cursor