# MySQL sort adding progressive id

Tags: mysql, database, ranking

i have a problem

i want to sort my table content with MySQL, and use results as ranking table in a game:

scores:
user | points

i have this query: `SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10`

how can i add a column in my query result to display every record with a progressive number?

i.e.

what my query is displaying:

```
mike        8000
al          7569
frank       7296
alex        7000
dana        6237
mark        6201
gankz       5766
mickeymouse 5420
donaldduck  5126
user        2569
```

what i want it to display:

```
**1** mike 8000
**2** al 7569
**3** frank 7296
**4** alex 7000
**5** dana 6237
**6** mark 6201
**7** gankz 5766
**8** mickeymouse 5420
**9** donaldduck 5126
**10** user 2569
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Row Rank in a MySQL View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964811/row-rank-in-a-mysql-view)

Comment: In particular, see OMGPonies' answer in the linked question.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index, user, points 
FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT TOP 10 CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Points)) AS RowRank, Users, Points FROM Scores
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't write comments yet, I would like to point out that when doing a select statement it is better practice to not use SELECT *. If you're only grabbing name and score, only select for those.

[What is the reason not to use select *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)