# MySQL: return result with its order

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to return result with its order?

Sample: Run the following query on the `quiz` table:

```
select q.category_id, q.quiz_id, concat('Quiz ',q.name) name
from quiz q
where q.category_id = 11
order by q.category_id ASC
limit 2
offset 2;
```

Table `quiz` (structure):

```
+-------------+---------+-------+
| category_id | quiz_id | name  |
+-------------+---------+-------+
| 10          | 10      | math  |
| 11          | 10      | sport |  => Quiz Sport 1
| 11          | 11      | sport |  => Quiz Sport 2
| 12          | 10      | Geo.  |
| 11          | 15      | sport |  => Quiz Sport 3
| 11          | 12      | sport |  => Quiz Sport 4
| 10          | 17      | math  |
| 11          | 20      | sport |  => Quiz Sport 5
| 11          | 22      | sport |  => Quiz Sport 6
| 10          | 19      | math  |
+-------------+---------+-------+
```

returns:

```
+-------------+---------+------------+
| category_id | quiz_id | name       |
+-------------+---------+------------+
| 11          | 15      | Quiz sport |
| 11          | 12      | Quiz sport |
+-------------+---------+------------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/110752/2

Is there a way to return a result with the Quiz number order, like this:

```
+-------------+---------+--------------+
| category_id | quiz_id | name         |
+-------------+---------+--------------+
| 11          | 15      | Quiz sport 3 |
| 11          | 12      | Quiz sport 4 |
+-------------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: You need to have another field to `order by` to determine the correct order.  Sql is stored unordered -- so you won't be able to guarantee the results unless you can order by another field.

Comment: This would be **much** easier in anything other than MySql, because for some reason MySql doesn't have windowing functions, even though they've been part of the ansi standard for more than 10 years. With a windowing function, this is a simple `row_number()` call, which is supported in Postgresql, Oracle, Sql Server, DB2, sybase, and anything else I can think of... but not mysql.

Comment: There is no primary key on this `quiz` table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Row Rank in a MySQL View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964811/row-rank-in-a-mysql-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to establish a row number to do this.  Doing so means you need a unique field to `order by` to ensure the order of the results.  You can get the row number using `user-defined variables` in mysql.  Here's an example reordering by `quiz_id`:

```
select * 
from (select q.category_id, q.quiz_id, @rn := @rn + 1, concat('Quiz ',q.name, @rn) name
    from quiz q, (select @rn := 0) t
    where q.category_id = 11
    order by q.category_id ASC, q.quiz_id) t
order by category_id ASC, quiz_id
limit 2
offset 2;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f62/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can either order by your primary key if you have one such as

```
select q.category_id, q.quiz_id, concat('Quiz ',q.name) name
from quiz q
where q.category_id = 11
order by q.id, q.category_id ASC
limit 2
offset 2;
```

If you don't I suggest you add a primary with [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070764/insert-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-mysql-database):

```
ALTER TABLE quiz ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

It does not *have* to be `PRIMARY` if for some reasons that doesn't work with what you do. You could also use the aforementioned statement to add an `rank` column which is also `auto_increment`

Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE quiz ADD rank INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

(Then run the first query.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question that helped me get to the answer for your question:
(Thanks to @OMG Ponies) [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964811/row-rank-in-a-mysql-view) (please read his answer to get more understanding about the issue)

Assuming that you want to count the quizzes sequentially:
Here is the [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/110752/11) to my answer.

Basically, you're counting the number of entries, and displaying that in a column.